# Concatenate font awesome icon with string

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

So im making a To do app and Im trying to add font-awesome icons to show a check mark whenever the toggle completed button is pressed. I can not add it via HTML because the list dynamically changes through JS. Here is the if/else that prints out the completed and non-completed tasks.

```js
  if (todo.completed === true) {
    todoTextDone = '(X)' + todo.todoText; // <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  } else {
    todoTextDone = '( )' + todo.todoText;
  }
```

I have tried document.write, document.querySelectory, document.getElementById. I tried creating a CSS class and selecting it from JS but it give's me an Object collection error. I have tried targeting the li to have a font awesome Icon before it in CSS and that did not work either! Am I attempting to use them in wrong way? By all theory the document.write method should have worked because It inserts HTML into the DOM so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always have the icon, then use CSS to hide it depending on the item's state (here indicated by a class):

```css
#toDo {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none
}

#toDo li .fa {
  color: green
}
#toDo li.open .fa {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul id="toDo">
  <li class="open"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> First item</li>
  <li class="done"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Second item</li>
</ul>
```

Don't use `document.write()` btw.

Comment: How would I add the open, and done classes to JS? It's easy to assign them in HTML. Whenever my tasks are not done it prints an ( ) and when they are done it prints (X). I thought it would be easy to replace those with a font awesome Icon

Comment: I have no idea how your code works, your snippet doesn't run and there's zero HTML. Therefore all I can do is show you how I would do it. Assuming you have an array `items` storing all the `<li>`s, you can use `items[i].className = "done";` to set the class. You _can_ also replace your `(X)` with the font-awesome HTML, but since I don't see the rest of your code, I have no idea why that doesn't work.

Comment: When you create the list items, you use `todoLi.textContent = todoTextDone;` Use `todoLi.innerHTML = todoTextDone;` instead, and the FA code will appear as icon, not as text.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create  element

```
var iEl = document.createElement('i');  
iEl.style.className = "fa fa-check";  
document.getElementById("yourElementId").appendChild(iEl);
```

Comment: Tried and it make's all the text disappear :(

Answer (score 0):

This Snippet uses only CSS and the [Font-Awesome stylesheet](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css). If you prefer other formats refer to the [cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)

**SNIPPET**

```css
.chx {
  display: none;
}
.chx + label {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.chx + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.chx + label span {
  background: #666;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.chx + label span {
  line-height: 100%;
}
#chx1:checked + label span:before {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: #F00;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#chx2:checked + label span:before {
  content: '\f04b';
  color: #0ff;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#chx2 + label span:before {
  content: '\f04c';
  color: #0ff;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#chx2:checked + label span:after {
  content: 'Play';
}
#chx2 + label span:after {
  content: 'Pause';
  font-family: Verdana;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<input id='chx1' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
<label for='chx1'><span></span>
</label>
<hr>
<input id='chx2' class='chx' type='checkbox'>
<label for='chx2'><span></span>
</label>
```